# FileWatcher on a directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark/Scala application and my requirement here is to look for a file in a directory
and process it and finally cleaning up that directory.

Isn't this possible to do this within the spark application itself like

```
- Watching for a file in a directory
- When it finds the file continue the process 
- Cleans up the directory before ending the app
- Repeat the above for the next new run and so on...
```

We currently do this `file-watching process` using an external application
so in order to remove the `dependency` on that `third-party application` 
we would like to do this within our spark/scala application itself.

Is there a feasible solution using just scala/spark for a file-watcher? 
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

File streams in spark streaming?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#file-streams